# Image creation align* environment in htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I have using `htlatex` for converting LaTeX to HTML. Everything is working fine except `\begin{align*}` environment is not converting to Image. Please find the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 3x+4&=16 \\
 3x&=16-4\ \hbox{Subtract 4 from both sides.} \\
 &=12 \\
 x&=\frac{12}{3}\ \hbox{Divide both sides by 3.} \\
 &=4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

`\frac{12}{13}` is only converted to Image remaining is not converting to Image format. How to get all the `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` in Image format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pic-align` option:

```
 htlatex sample "xhtml, pic-align"
```

for more available options see [CVR's blog](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=504), more similar options for pictorial math exist.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. I have using own config file so that used `htlatex foo.tex my,pic-align"`. It's working fine. If giving `space` after `,` it's not converting.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250643/latex-to-html-problem-with-fractions?noredirect=1#comment597345_250643

I cant get around using the pic-align option. I m not used to the command environment. How do I have to type the command? It always says cant find pic-align.cdf

I usally write. 

htlatex test.tex , pic-align

Comment: @MaxM qotes around `"xhtml, pic-align"` are important, you write it incorrectly

Comment: Thanks the command helped, but I still have blurry images for the fraction.