# Latex to HTML problem with fractions

Tags: htlatex

im using htlatex to transcript a latex file to html for a web application. It seems to work fine with most of my equations, but as soon as I use \frac or \dfrac the images of the equations become very blurry.  Somehow I also had to stop using the equation environment in favor of $ $.

Im not sure if a minimum example would help?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
$F_i=\left(\dfrac{L_i}{Y_i}\right)^\alpha $
\end{document}
```

After using "htlatex file.tex" the output is realy blurry

Comment: Confirmed: with `\[...\]` everything is blurry, and with `$ ... $`, only the fraction is. Can't help you though.

Comment: the math is converted as images by default. it is better to use mathml with mathjax, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68962/2891

Comment: Thanks that solution seems a bit above my head. I was hoping for a more dirty quick fix

Comment: This is a easiest solution, other solutions require config files editing and produce inferior results

Comment: Ok  I think i managed somehow. I created the cfg file with my word editor. and used your command without the end part. cause then it did not create a new html file 
so I used:  htlatex frac.tex "ht5mjlatex.cfg, charset=utf-8"

Comment: Essentially this is a dupe, or at least that points the way to a solution so I've closed.